# How to set environment variable inside ubuntu so that they can be access by the nginx, sidekiq and rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-5

How to set environment variable in side ubuntu so that they can be access by the nginx, sidekiq and rails application both in development and production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple ways but one possible approach is:

set environment variable in the /etc/environment file:

```
sudo vim /etc/environment
```

Now set values as:

```
APP_URL="http://lcoalhost:3000"
APP_HOST="127.0.0.1"
EMAIL_HOST="127.0.0.1"
```